# UseSqlServer method missing MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to implement Entity Framework 7 in MVC 6, and on this page [here](https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/blob/master/src/MusicStore/Startup.cs#l44-49) it says to do

```
services.AddEntityFramework()
    .AddSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<MusicStoreContext>(options =>
                        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));
```

But for me, the `UseSqlServer` method isn't visible?  Anyone know how to make it visible?  Or is this an old way of configuring entity framework?

My `startup.cs` file looks like this

```
using FluentValidation;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel;
using Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection;

namespace me.namespace.project
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            // Setup configuration sources.
            Configuration = new Configuration()
                .AddJsonFile("config.json")
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            // entity framework
            services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<DataContext>();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

`UseSqlServer` is an extension method in the namespace `Microsoft.Data.Entity` so you need to import that in your code, like this:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what i needed

Comment: Works perfectly...got another problem now saying "No database providers are configured. Configure a database provider by overriding OnConfiguring in your DbContext class or in the AddDbContext method when setting up services." not sure why, as my startup.cs file is stating the conectionstring?

Comment: Sounds easy enough to fix, but that's another question :)

Comment: Was not the issues - Needed @Win's comment from another answer.

Answer (score 48):

Install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 1.0.1 package works for me
Version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore is 1.1.0

Comment: This is the correct answer as of 3/24/2017. NuGet: [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer/).

Comment: Works like a charm  install-package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Answer (score 28):

Since this has been posted, assemblies have been renamed. As part of EntityFrameworkCore you now need to add a using statement the following

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

And the .UseSqlServer extension method to configure your context will become available

Answer (score 22):

It's a `NuGet Packages Problem`

Install the following Packages  and with its Proper Versions

```
 1.  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore(Latest Version)
 2.  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer(1.0.4 Version)
```

Comment: on 08/17/2022, this is still a missing package with .Net 6's EF Core library. I had to pull down the SqlServer package from NuGet to get the .UseSqlServer() extension.

Answer (score 0):

install the following package
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer version 6.0.24
[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCAMK.png)
it's working for me