# UseSqlServer missing from AddDbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Just upgraded to asp.net core 2.1 and it seems like ***UseSqlServer*** no longer exists in the options for ***AddDbContext***. (where I pass in the connectionstring)

What am I supposed to use instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UseSqlServer method missing MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064164/usesqlserver-method-missing-mvc-6)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Added nuget package *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer* and it worked again

Answer (score 12):

You must add

`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

as explained in https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f9cdb8de-0c4c-47ae-b0be-e4b52a887183/dbcontextoptionsbuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-usesqlserver?forum=adodotnetentityframework