# UseSqlServer is missing and conflicting refrences?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget

Im trying to follow a [Entity Framework Core video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bmbeBFfiuck&t=658s) in a .NET Core 2.1 DAL class library. In the DbContext.OnCofiguring the following code is placed :

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server*.");
    }
```

The problem is that the UseSQLServer is missing? From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138635/usesqlserver-missing-from-adddbcontext) its suggested to add *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer* nuget. When doing this I get some version conflicts that I dont know how to solve :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition
>   for 'UseSqlServer' and no accessible extension method 'UseSqlServer'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   DataAccessLayer

--

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for
>   'DataAccessLayer'.

--

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error NU1605  Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration from 2.2.0 to 2.1.1. Reference the
>   package directly from the project to select a different version.
>   DataAccessLayer -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.2.3 ->
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.2.3 ->
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.3 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
>   2.2.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder 2.2.0 -> Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.2.0)   DataAccessLayer ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (>= 2.1.1) DataAccessLayer

--

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error NU1605  Detected package downgrade:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection from 2.2.0 to 2.1.1.
>   Reference the package directly from the project to select a different
>   version.   DataAccessLayer -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
>   2.2.3 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.2.3 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.3 ->
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 2.2.0)   DataAccessLayer
>   -> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 2.1.1)    DataAccessLayer

--

I suspect that the project is using a couple of nuget packages and some of them is referencing a diffrent version of another nuget or dll.

It suggest to reference a package direcly? Does this mean that I should reference a dll manually? Where do I get the dll from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default severity for [NU1605](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605) is warning and since you're seeing it as an error, it means that your project has opt-in'ed into treating errors as warnings.

The reason for the package downgrade is probably due to [NuGet's nearest-wins rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/dependency-resolution#nearest-wins). The only way to avoid a downgrade is to add a PackageReference to the downgraded package to your project, that way the version you select is always nearest and transient dependencies can never downgrade it.

Otherwise you stop shooting yourself in the foot by either turning off "treat all warnings as errors" and list only the specific warnings you want treated as errors. Or, add NU1605 to the list of warnings to suppress (`<NoWarn>` in the csproj).

Comment: Turning of the "treat all warnings as errors" do not solve the problem. It looks like it goes away when only building that DAL project but when building the BLL that references de DAL I get the same error on both BLL and DAL.

Can you explain the PackageReference part?

Comment: I saw that the warning NU1605 is specified per default on all the solution projects to treat them specifically as errors. This is turned off now.

Comment: I change most of the nuggets to 2.1.1, no I dont get any errors or warnings?

Comment: your last comment ends in a question mark, but the sentence is a statement not a question. If you're trying to ask something, I don't know what you're asking.